# how to make static libraries runtime requirement for the CRT {static, DLL} vary by project?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I have a .lib written in C++ that I use in two different ways

1. linked to a .EXE that can not depend on a dynamically loaded CRT
2. a managed C++ DLL that must use the dynamically loaded CRT

...if I specify the runtime library requirement for the lib to be a DLL, #1 is happy, but #2 is not.  if I specify the runtime library requirement for the lib to be static #1 becomes unhappy while #2 is happy

how can I fix this?  I'd *really* rather not have two projects/solutions?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add new configurations to your solution.

At the moment you will most likely have configurations called `Debug` and `Release`.

Ensure that both configurations are using the dynamically loaded CRT.

Copy the `Debug` configuration as `Debug Static` and `Release` as `Release Static`.  Rename `Debug` to `Debug Dynamic` and `Release` to `Release Dynamic`.

Change the two static configurations to use the static CRT.

When you build the project you will get separate `Release Dynamic` and `Release Static` versions of the library you can use with the managed DLL and the EXE respectively.